# SDK7 Format number

Tags: ios, objective-c

Need to format number four digits, no decimal, including 0 in the left, e.g. 0012. I am writing this code on Xcode for iPhone.

```
if (Tipo.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 ) { 
   float a = [N1.text floatValue];  float b = [N2.text floatValue];  
   float c = a*b;  
   R.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f",c];  
}
```

Comment: You always get and want 00 before your result number ?

Comment: You want to display a 4 digit int, but you are using floats? I smell something there. Try converting to int and then formatting it.

Comment: Hi Jordan, what I got is 12 instead of 0012.

Comment: @Abizern, int works better, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this, let me know if helps

```
 self.yourTimeHere.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.%d", (int)hours, (int)minutes];
```